# HTTP integration tests

Tags: go, integration-testing

I have a small service written in Go. I'm already testing it with `httptest` et al, but, I'm mocking the database and etc...

What I would like to do:

- Start up the very same server I use in production with an empty database
- Run tests against it using HTTP
- Get the coverage of those tests

The empty database part is not a problem, since I made everything configurable via environment variables.

Make requests to it is also not the problem, as it is just standard Go code...

The problem is: I don't know how to start the server in a way that I could measure the coverage of it (and it's sub-packages). Also, the main server code is inside a `main` function... I don't even know if I can call it from somewhere else (I tried the standard way, but not with reflection and stuff like that).

I'm kind of new using Go, so, this I might be talking nonsense.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to get the code coverage of these httptest integration tests?

Comment: @AaronGreenlee unfortunately not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start the http server in your test, and make requests against it.

For more convenience, you can use [`httptest.Server`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#Server) in the test, and give it your primary http.Handler. The `httptest.Server` has some methods to better control to start and stop the server, and provides a `URL` field to give you the local address of the server.

```
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
}))
defer ts.Close()

res, err := http.Get(ts.URL)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
greeting, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
res.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("%s", greeting)
```

Comment: understood... is there a way to integrate it with my already created handlers? I believe I wasn't clear... I want to test the same code which goes to production... the routes, middlewares... everything... I'll study this httptest.Server, but, seems like it will not work with my echo (https://github.com/labstack/echo) code :/ Thanks, BTW!

Comment: @caarlos0: the httptest.Server constructors take an http.Handler as their argument. You can plug in whatever handlers, muxers, etc you want, just like you would with the standard http.Server.

Comment: This is an unit testing example for `net/http`. Integration tests might be requesting without involving handlers in tests, as if they're inside of an external remote api.